# How can I modify or replace each value in a dictionary in the same way?

Tags: python

Given a dictionary like `myDict = {'ten': 10, 'fourteen': 14, 'six': 6}`, how can I modify each of the values? For example, I'd like to divide each value by two, so that `myDict` becomes `{'ten': 5, 'fourteen': 7, 'six': 3}` (in place, not creating a new dictionary).

Comment: note that it is customary that python variables are named with_underscores and not camelCase.

Comment: @Elazar I thought it was almost entirely personal preference

Comment: Python has a strong culture with somewhat strict conventions. I am sure you already heard about writing *pythonic* code. I recommend you to read [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterate over keys, and use them to access, modify and assign back the corresponding values. For example:

```
for k in myDict:
    myDict[k] /= 2
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I wanted to change the original dict, not just return the values divided by 2. Question might have been a little unclear.

Answer (score 13):

To iterate over keys and values:

```
for key, value in myDict.items():
    myDict[key] = value / 2
```

The default loop over a dictionary iterates over its keys, like

```
for key in myDict:
    myDict[key] /= 2
```

or you could use a map or a comprehension.

map:

```
myDict = map(lambda item: (item[0], item[1] / 2), myDict)
```

comprehension:

```
myDict = { k: v / 2 for k, v in myDict.items() }
```

Comment: You did not answer the actual question: how to change each value.

Comment: @Elazar he asked to perform an operation and gave an example of a non-modifying division by 2; I assumed he was using it as an example of some more complex iteration

Comment: He obviously intended to modify the value, it just didn't work for him (because he did it wrong).

Comment: @Elazar yeah reading a few more times I realized you're right

Comment: `value /= 2` may or may not change the dictionary, depending on the type of `value`. I think it is better not to show it as an example for anything; it is rather confusing.

Comment: note that `myDict[key] = myDict[key] / 2` *forces* double lookup in `myDict`, even when there is a way to optimize `myDict[key] /= 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`dict.items()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method and a [dict comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```py
dic = {'ten': 10, 'fourteen': 14, 'six': 6}
print({k: v/2 for k, v in dic.items()})
```

Output:

```
{'ten': 5.0, 'six': 3.0, 'fourteen': 7.0}
```

Comment: I've made an edit to add that language hint back in - and changed *list comprehension* to *dict comprehension*, with a link that explains how they both (along with generator expressions, et al) work.

Comment: +1, this answer is now a good one. Dict comprehensions are the best (and most readable and concise) way to do this kind of thing.

Comment: @Lattyware they are awesome, but they do not change the dict *in-place*.

Comment: @Elazar You can call `dict.update()` if you need to - but is there any reason to assume the asker *needs* it in-place? The OP assumes that will be the way the solution works, but it's unlikely he actually *needs* it to be in-place.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3:

```
>>> my_dict = {'ten': 10, 'fourteen': 14, 'six': 6}
>>> for key, value in my_dict.items():
       my_dict[key] = value / 2
>>> my_dict
{'fourteen': 7.0, 'six': 3.0, 'ten': 5.0}
```

This changes the original dictionary. Use `//` instead of `/` to get floor division.